# Thread local context for Hibernate session and asynchronous request processing

Tags: hibernate, asynchronous, jetty, embedded-jetty

Our application utilises Jetty 7.x to expose some REST API over HTTP. In the past the application was dependent on Hibernate 3.2.6 with thread local session context, where each session was transaction-bound and would be closed upon transaction commit or rollback.

Such configuration would not work properly in case of an async channel used by Jetty (SelectChannelConnector). Simultaneous (or nearly simultaneous) requests would result in error complaining about a closed Hibernate session. So, it would seem as if the same thread-bound Hibernate session was reused in cases where the same thread was used by Jetty to handle multiple HTTP requests. In order to void this problem, BlockingChannelConnector was used instead of SelectChannelConnector, and everything worked well.

However, after migrating to Hibernate 3.6.x branch it would appear that SelectChannelConnector can be used without resulting in the error describe above. Those tests with requests running in parallel that would fail in the past do not fail under Hibernate 3.6.x, but I'm not certain that this is a sufficient condition to prove that session handling is operating correctly.

Could anyone with deeper understanding comment please whether it is safe to use a thread local and transaction-bound Hibernate session in an async environment where the same thread can be reused for handling multiple HTTP request?

Please note that request-bound session management is not the best option in our case. Thus, we'd like to stick with a thread local or potentially some custom session context approach.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully used ThreadLocal container to store EntityManager instances with Hibernate 4.2.2.
Currently we remove instances from container after commit/rollback, but just in case some thread might be stopped - in order not to keep unused instances.
But anyway I clearly remember that it worked perfectly while keeping EM instances in container.